# how to run tensorflow on spyder using windows 10?

Tags: python, spyder, tensorflow

i try to run tensorflow on my spyder, it can not work. but when i try to run tensorflow on cmd, it works well. i already install tensorflow using this script "pip install tensorflow" and it is successfull. i'm using windows 10 and gpu version. how can i run tensorflow on my spyder and have the module of tensorflow?
[this is when i run on cmd and successsfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvAhf.png)
[this is when i run on spyder and not succesfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS4Pm.png)

for anybody who can help me i really appreciate it.
anyway i'm a newbie on python actually on tensorflow . 
thank you

Comment: You're on windows so your PATH is probably jacked up. Take a look at https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation

Comment: thank you. it works for me.